# Return the proportionate share of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

just for example lets say I have this table sales(ID,type,price).

Now, for each entry I have to return its proportion of its type sellings.

For instance, if my total revenue from selling bikes is 1000, and I sold 1 pair of bike for 100 so it's proportion will be 0.1.

How do I implement it over SQL?
Thanks!

Comment: sample data and expected output will be great, and easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up:

```
create table sales (
    ID numeric,
    type varchar(20),
    price decimal
);

insert into sales values (1,'bike','900.00');
insert into sales values (2,'bike','100.00');
```

Query:

```
select s1.ID, s1.type, s1.price, (s1.price/s2.sum_price) as proportion
from sales s1
inner join (
    select type, sum(price) as sum_price
    from sales
    group by type
) s2
on s1.type = s2.type;
```

The inner query gets all the sums by type.  This is an emulation of the `sum(col2) over (partition by col2)` which is available in some databases but not in MySQL.